# MultiThreading C# Task.Run o new Task() a instancia?

Tags: c#, hilos

Estoy repasando Multithreading y estoy (redundancia) probando maneras de usar los tasks, me hice una clase static para prueba,

```
static class PruebaTask
{
    public static void usoTasks()
    {
        DateTime Inicio = DateTime.Now;

        Task task;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
        {
            task = new Task(() => metodoPrueba());

            //task = Task.Run(() => metodoPrueba());//así no requiere instancia
        }

        MessageBox.Show("El task Tardó" + (DateTime.Now - Inicio)+ " thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);


    }

    static void metodoPrueba()
    {
        double d = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            d = 12445 / 434 * 495 / 3.09;
        }
    }

}
```

Y lo llamo desde aquí

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //PruebaThread.usoThreads();
        PruebaTask.usoTasks();
        //PruebaBox.probarMsg();
    }
```

Mi pregunta es:

Que diferencia hay entre, estas 2 sentencias:

```
task = new Task(() => metodoPrueba());

task = Task.Run(() => metodoPrueba());
```

la segunda tambien se puede dejar solamente como :

```
Task.Run(() => metodoPrueba());
```

Devuelve un Task así que lo puedo asígnar a una variable Task, pero al final el resultado es el mismo

lo que veo esque al usar `task = new Task(() => metodoPrueba());` tarda la maravillosa cantidad de o.3 segundos, en cambio con `Task.Run(() => metodoPrueba());` tarda practicamente 1 minuto, y está haciendodolo 5 millones de veces.

Es evidente la diferencia, pero alguien sabe por qué sucede esto?

(Apenas me estoy iniciando en C#, aún no comienzo con await ni async,, ya también probé con instancias nuevas de Threads directamente, y tarda muchisimo aun, ahí, tengo entendido que golpea el rendimiento al crear nuevos thread, y en cambio, los Tasks son optimizaciones para usar Threads ya existentes, si estoy mal corriganme)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `new Task(...)` es la opción que te da todo el control de cómo y cuando se ejecuta, obtienes una referencia a la tarea pero no se ejecuta hasta que lo indiques llamando al método `Start`.  No se recomienda usar esta opción a menos que sea necesario, llamar por separado a `Start` tiene un costo de rendimiento.
- `Task.Factory.StartNew()` sirve para crear y programar la ejecución de la tarea en un solo método.  Recibe los mismos parámetros, tiene las mismas sobrecargas que el constructor y como ya te diste cuenta es equivalente (pero sin impacto de rendimiento) a:

  ```
  var task = new Task(...);
  task.Start();
  ```
- `Task.Run` es la opción más recomendada y es equivalente a llamar a `Task.Factory.StartNew()` con parámetros diferentes al comportamiento por defecto pero que son deseables en la mayoría de escenarios:

  ```
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {...}, 
      CancellationToken.None, 
      TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, 
      TaskScheduler.Default);
  ```

Comment: Vaya, me estoy riendo de mi, por no ver ese pequeño detalle jeje
Sabes entonces, sabes cual es la diferencia con esta otra sentencia?
La descripcion dice "crea e inicia una nueva tarea" 


                *`task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => metodoPrueba(i));`*



Puedo suponer que es lo mismo que:



*   ` task = new Task(() => metodoPrueba());
    task.Start();`*

Solo que ahorra código